# 404 header in wordpress with php function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, svg, header

I have build a 404 page for my wordpress website. In my `404.php`I call the header function with `<?php get_header(); ?>`. I want to replace my normal Logo with a 404 Logo. In my `header.php` I add the following function:

```
<?php

    if ( is_404()){
        echo "test";
    }
    else {
        echo "test1";
    }
        

?>
```

It is only for testing if I can do another thing to a 404 page and it is working.

Now I want to replace for the 404 page my logo. The Logo is a `svg` in both cases.
This is the relevant part of the `header.php`:

```
    <header class="m-header">
        <div class="m-header-content">
            <div class="m-header-logo">
                 <a href="/">
                    <svg>
                        <title>test<title>
                        <path class="st0" d="svgpath....."/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
        <div>
     
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
            'container_class' => 'm-header-menu') );
        ?>
    </header>
```

Can someone give me an example how I can change the `<svg>` with my function at the top? Or can someone give me a documentation about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a conditional inside your markup at `header.php` for e.g.

```
              <?php if (is_404()) { ?>
                   // Your 404 svg markup here.
                  <svg>
                   <title>404 Logo<title>
                     <path class="st0" d="svgpath....."/>
                  </svg>
                <?php else { ?>
                 // Your regular logo svg here.
                 <svg>
                   <title>Site Logo<title>
                     <path class="st0" d="svgpath....."/>
                </svg>
              <?php } ?>
```

In your provided header markup you can apply this like so -

```
<header class="m-header">
    <div class="m-header-content">
        <div class="m-header-logo">
             <a href="/">
                <?php if ( is_404() ) { ?>
                   // Your 404 svg markup here.
                  <svg>
                   <title>404 Logo<title>
                     <path class="st0" d="svgpath....."/>
                  </svg>
                <?php else { ?>
                 // Your regular logo svg here.
                 <svg>
                   <title>Site Logo<title>
                     <path class="st0" d="svgpath....."/>
                </svg>
              <?php } ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    <div>
 
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
        'container_class' => 'm-header-menu') );
    ?>
</header>
```

P.S. for the bad formatting, answered via phone.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your 404 function at the top does the right thing, it should work something like this.

`->` SVG Path HTML as a string, make sure quotes are escaped `[ " ] -> [ \" ]`

```
<header class="m-header">
    <div class="m-header-content">
        <div class="m-header-logo">
            <svg>
                <?php
                if ( is_404()){
                    echo "<title>404 svg</title>";
                    echo "<path class=\"st0\" d=\"svgpath.....\"/>"; // 404 SVG Path
                } else {
                    echo "regular svg";
                    echo "<path class=\"st0\" d=\"svgpath.....\"/>"; // SVG Path
                }
                ?>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>
    <div>
    
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
        'container_class' => 'm-header-menu') );
    ?>
</header>
```